# NativeScript Webview newbie questions

Tags: webview, nativescript

I am experimenting with using NativeScript to speed up the process of porting an existing Android app to iOS.  The app in question uses a great deal of SVG manipulation in a Cordova webview.  To keep things simple I want to port all of my existing Webview side code - in essence the entire existing Cordova www folder and its contents - over to the new NativeScript app.  The WebView talks to a custom Cordova plugin which I use to talk with my servers to do such things as get new SVGs to show, keep track of user actions etc.

If I an get through these teething issues I am considering using [this component](http://shripalsoni.com/blog/nativescript-webview-native-bi-directional-communication/) to implement bi-direction communications between by current webview JS code and the, new, NativeScript backend that will replace my current Cordova plugin.  Someone here is bound to tell me that I don't need to do that... .  However, doing so would mean throwing out the baby with the bathwater and rewriting all of my current Webview ES6/JS/CSS code.

This is pretty much Day 1 for me with NativeScript and I have run into a few issues.

- I find that I cannot get rid of the ActionBar even though I have followed the [instructions here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#showing-or-hiding-the-actionbar) and set the action bar to hidden.
- I can use the following markup in `home.component.html`

to show external web content.  However, what I want to really do is to show the local HTML file that is in the www folder in the following folder hierarchy

```
app
|
 ____home
|
 ____www
      |
       ______ index.html
      |
       ______css
      |
       ______ tpl
      |
       .....
```

However, when I use the markup

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" >
 <WebView src="~/www/index.html"></WebView>
</Page>
```

I am shown the error message

> The webpage at file:///data/data/com.example.myapp/files/app/www/index.html is not available.

I'd be most grateful to anyone  who might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong here - and also, how I can get rid of that action bar which is currently showing the app title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About using local HTML file**

Is your local HTML file recognized by Webpack (which is enabled by default in NativeScript)? Try to explicitly add the local HTML file to your **webpack.config.js** file. This way Webpack will "know" that it will have to bundle this file as well.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: { glob: "<path-to-your-custom-file-here>/index.html" } }, // HERE
    { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
]
```

Example [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L253)

**About hiding the ActionBar**

***NativeScript Core*** only: Try hiding the action bar directly for the frame that holds the page. See the related documentation [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/frame#action-bar-visibility)

***NativeScript Angular***: The `page-router-outlet` will have an action bar by default (you can hide it by using the Page DI as done [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/e4310a16048c520016f0360486faaa1f8f501cb0/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L35)). Otherwise, you could create a `router-outlet` (instead of `page-router-outlet`). The `router-outler` won't have the mobile-specific ActionBar.